# Adding animation to Android application

Tags: animation, customization

I'm currently working on a new app, and I want to add customized animations to it (not talking about activity transitions). 
To show you exactly what I mean, take a look at this video at 2:30-2:33:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBMdjX5bbvk&nohtml5=False

You see the chest jumping to the screen and opens smoothly with beautiful animation? 
I'd really like to know how can it be added to an Android app, is it a frame animation? 
I mean, I can make this animation, in 2D, I just want to know how to add it (I'm using Android Studio) without causing memory overflow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you question:

> You see the chest jumping to the screen and opens smoothly with
>   beautiful animation? I'd really like to know how can it be added to an
>   Android app, is it a frame animation?

I don't think it is a frame animation. I guess this has been implemented using OpenGL. You can find the official tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html).

If you want to make simple 2d animations, you can use the `AnimationDrawable` api provided by android. You basically need frames for the sequence of animations and then you can create the animation using the following code:

```
// you would need an `ImageView` object as a placeholder for the animation
ImageView mMascotView = findViewById(...);

// prepare the animation object ..
AnimationDrawable mMascotAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();

final int frameTime = 250; // time in milliseconds

// adding the frames to the animation object. You can specify different
// times for each of these in milliseconds
mMascotAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.frame1),frameTime);
mMascotAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.frame2),frameTime);
mMascotAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.frame3),frameTime);


// make it loop infinitely ..
mMascotAnimation.setOneShot(false);

// set the background of the `ImageView` as the `AnimationDrawable`object ..
mMascotView.setBackground(mMascotAnimation);

// start the animation ..
mMascotAnimation.start();
```

**Note:** You should not call the `AnimationDrawable.start()`inside the `onCreate()` method of the activity. The views are not ready yet. You should use the callback on `onWindowFocusChanged()` method and  start the animation there:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)
{
      //Start animation here
      if(hasFocus) {
           mMascotAnimation.start();
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, well detailed